# Using NavigationPage in .NET MAUI

Tags: navigation, maui, .net-maui

I'm having a hard time trying to use NavigationPage instead of ContentPage. When I try to use the type NavigationPage for my MainPage base class, and change ContentPage to NavigationPage in the XAML, it won't let me put any controls on it without throwing an error. What good is a blank page?

Are you even supposed to use the type NavigationPage? You can use NavigationPage.PropertyName in a ContentPage, but not all of the properties work. The MAUI Docs clearly show a plethora of properties to work with, but I only can use a fraction of them.

No amount of Google-Fu has helped me. The docs don't give very good examples to follow, and most articles are of no help explaining how to properly and thoroughly use NavigationPage.

Does anybody out there know how to use NavigationPage properly?

Comment: NavigationPage is a wrapper for other pages (like ContentPage), it doesn't contain any content itself.

Comment: In addition, you might or might not want to have NavigationPage combined with the default Shell. One approach is to find `MainPage = new AppShell();` or similar in App.xaml.cs, and change it to `MainPage = new NavigationPage();`. Doing this, you would NOT do Navigation the "Shell" way (which is what Maui documents). Instead, navigation would be controlled by NavigationPage. If Maui's NavigationPage doc is not helpful enough, see also Xamarin Forms documentation. There are also Xamarin Forms youtube videos, tutorials, and sample code, that may give more of a feel for how to use NavigationPage.